# Im unable to delete the records present int he Pivot Table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, blogs

I have five tables:

- Post
- category
- Tags
- category_post
- post_tag

The problem that I am getting is that if I delete the post then it should also delete all the relations of that post in all the tables where it is related. But the system is performing the total opposite it is only deleting the post in the post table.

I found a solution which was

```
$table->engine='InnoDB'
```

but my problem still remains the same

This is my Migration for the Category_post Pivot Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('post_id')->index()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->index()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is what I am doing in the controller

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post=Post::find($post->id);
    $post->delete();
    return redirect('admin/post')->with('message','Deleted Sucessfully');
}
```

I also Tried this

```
  public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post=Post::find($post->id);
    $post->categories()->delete();
    $post->tags()->delete();
    $post->delete();
    return redirect('admin/post')->with('message','Deleted Sucessfully');
}
```

But got the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pivot tables for ManyToMany relationships in Laravel, you should detach the associated tags and categories with the Post model instead of deleting them as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)
Besides, your controller code is deleting the tags and categories **models** and not the association which would corrupt any other posts that are attached to those tags and categories.
Here's an example of the correct way to do it
In your `tags` migrations

```php
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // Any other columns goes here
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('post_id');
            $table->bigInteger('tag_id');
            // ensures a specific post can be associated a specific tag only once
            $table->primary(['post_id', 'tag_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post_tag');
        Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
    }
```

Do the same thing for categories migration
Specify the `ManyToMany` relationship in your Eloquent model like so

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Now when associating tags/categories with a post use the `attach` method

```php
$post = Post::create([]); // this is only sample code, fill your data as usual
$tag = Tag::create([]);
$category = Category::create([]);
// You can either attach by the model itself or ID
$post->tags()->attach($tag);
$post->categories()->attach($category);
```

And finally when destroying the Post model, just deassociate the relationship with the tags and categories instead of deleting them using the `detach` method like so

```php
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
   $post->categories()->detach();
   $post->tags()->detach();
   $post->delete();
   return redirect('admin/post')->with('message','Deleted Sucessfully');
}
```

Comment: I am only deleting the relations in the pivot table. It has nothing to do with the categories and tags. So detaching the values in the pivot table has no harm.